# Not able to refresh spring oauth2 token with multiple authentication provider

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to create an oauth2-enabled auth server which is able to authenticate users with two authentication providers: the former is in-memory (for default user-passwords) the latter is an external LDAP server (by now i'm using the example from gs-authenticating-ldap-complete).

I'm able to successfully retrieve an access token for any user, but i'm only able to use the refresh token for retrieving a new token for any user that is registered in the LDAP server. While everything is fine if I try to refresh an in-memory user's token, with the LDAP ones I get: `401 Unauthorized { "error": "unauthorized", "error_description": "ben" }` where "ben" is the user id.

As far as I know (after some debugging) the exception occurs in DefaultTokenServices.java:150.

In the following I report the configuration classes I'm using.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(6)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class DefaultUsersAuthConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN").and().withUser("guest")
                    .password("guest").roles("USER");
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class LDAPAuthConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people").groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                    .userDetailsContextMapper(new MyLdapUserDetailsMapper()).contextSource()
                    .ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");
        }

    }

    protected static class MyLdapUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper {

        @Override
        public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            final UserDetails originalUser = super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);

            final Set<GrantedAuthority> newAuth = new HashSet<>(originalUser.getAuthorities());
            newAuth.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_EXTRA_ROLE"));

            return new User(originalUser.getUsername(), originalUser.getPassword(), originalUser.isEnabled(),
                    originalUser.isAccountNonExpired(), originalUser.isCredentialsNonExpired(),
                    originalUser.isAccountNonLocked(), newAuth);
        }

    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("acme").secret("acmesecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "client_credentials")
                .scopes("read", "write", "openid").autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/me").authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using spring-boot 1.3.2.RELEASE. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you do "While everything is fine if I try to refresh an in-memory user's token, with the LDAP ones I get"? Please give the URLs and Request Parameters

Comment: `POST /oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=1a148f38-8309-4d18-86d2-89fd5d1c1509 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic YWNtZTphY21lc2VjcmV0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e12b5a63-9a77-4536-461c-63e00f25bb60
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
` If I use the refresh token for user ben I get the new access token, while with user ben I get the 401